# How to convert python data frame to json of fixed keys and dataframe columns as values

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Required to convert dataframe values into json format which will be feed for an external reporting system. Sample dataframe values and required json format is shared below.
Note: These Category can span to 1000 records or even more. Required to process the data efficiently

Data Frame Values

```
    **Category**   **catgName**    **catgCode**
    Vegies     Carrot  V001
    Fruit      Mango   F001
    Leaf       Mint    L001
    ExtFruit   Berry   EF01
    Fruit      Papaya  F002
    Vegies     Tomato  V002
```

Required Json Output

```
    {
        "externalFeed": {
            "Vegies": {
                "count": "2",
                "details": [{
                        "catgName": "Carrot",
                        "catgCode": "V001"
                    },
                    {
                        "catgName": "Tomato",
                        "catgCode": "V002"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Fruit": {
                "count": "2",
                "details": [{
                        "catgName": "Mango",
                        "catgCode": "F001"
                    },
                    {
                        "catgName": "Papaya",
                        "catgCode": "F002"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Leaf": {
                "count": "1",
                "details": [{
                            "catgName": "Mint",
                            "catgCode": "L001"
                        }
                    ]
            },
            "ExtFruit": {
                    "count": "1",
                    "details": [{
                            "catgName": "Berry",
                            "catgCode": "EF01"
                        }
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have your data so I assumed your data is in CSV file

```
import pandas as panda
reader = panda.read_csv('a.csv', chunksize=100)
for chunk in reader:
    x = chunk.to_records().tolist()
    result = {'externalFeed': {}}
    for item in x:
        if result['externalFeed'].get(item[1], None) is not None:
            result['externalFeed'][item[1]]['count'] += 1
            result['externalFeed'][item[1]]['details'].append(
                {'catgName': item[2], 'catgCode': item[3]})
        else:
            result['externalFeed'].update({item[1]: {'count': 1,
                                             'details': [{'catgName': item[2],
                                                           'catgCode': item[3]}]}})
    print(result)
reader.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Jay..
The input is read from database and stored as dataframe..

Comment: @lakksv if this works for you then you can accept the answer or share  your data read code so that I can change it accordingly